# I'm getting a null reference exception when trying to check if an excel cell value is blank

Tags: vb.net, excel

The following code is erroring out on the "cururentcol =" line.

```
 For Each del In finalsheet.Range("a3:" & lastcolll & "3").Value


       currentcol = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(del.Column)

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(finalsheet.Range(currentcol & "3").Value)) Then

'My code

end if

next
```

I have also tried doing

```
if del.value = ""
if del.value = Nothing
```

to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, had .value at the end of the for each line. My mistake. Works after removing it.